# Automatically refactor C++ classes into separate files

Tags: c++, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I've inherited a fairly big project with tens-of-thousands of lines, but the previous developers packed them into 6 files only (OMG!)...

So for the sake of readability I would like to automatically split all the classes into their own cpp/h files.

Is there any tool capable of such a thing?

Comment: Each class per file does not necessarily mean better readability. You should determine what needs to be split yourself.

Comment: You will have to reveal the platform and editor you are currently using as lots of the tools are specific to platform, editor, or development environment. You might already have such tools and just don't know it!

Comment: You can [use Python and libclang](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang/).

Answer (score 1):

What you need in order to refactor your C++ code base is a tool that can parse C++, retaining the headers files, yet follow the #includes and process them, too.   You have to construct an "a-depends-on-b" mapping for every pair of dependent items, and then you have to cluster them.  Finally, you have to be able to regenerate the source code according to the clustering.

And you want to do this over a complete code base, not just one compilation unit.

This is a pretty hard tool to find :-}  I don't think you'll find it off the shelf.

Our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit has much of this.  It is a general program analysis and transformation system, has a full C++ front end, and has a controllable preprocessor, so it can expand/not expand the #includes as necessary.   It can capture a-depends-on-b relations (we've done this on a C system of 26 million lines of code), and it has the proven capability to reason about preprocessor conditions symbolically; there's the potential to capture "a-depends-on-b if ".

With that information, you need clustering.  I think to do this, you need some kind of generic clustering algorithm, and some user input to override it ("I insist, leave this #include file alone, and these two apparantly unrelated things go together").  The program ransformation part of DMS can then be used to mechanically split code and include files into grouped, dependent declarations.

DMS is a complex tool; after all, it has to deal with nasty things like C++.  Configuring it to do the above tasks isn't trivial, but I think it within technical reach.

However, none of this will help you with your immediate issue of acquiring a tool to help you solve your problem today.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is no tool that will do that task automatically.  This is still an active research area.  For example, see "[Towards Automating Class-Splitting Using Betweenness Clustering](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5431726)".  I know of a couple of tools for Java that provide some assistance ([JDeodorant](http://www.jdeodorant.com/), [ext-c](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ext-c)), but these are not fully automatic.  I don't know of any C++ tools.

Answer (score -5):

You don't say what editor or platform you are using and so it isn't clear why large files are a problem.

My guess is that this is your solution:

- Get a better editor which can handle large files.

A good editor should be able to find a class by name, have a class browser which enables you to jump to the definition of any class, member, function, or any other definition, find uses of any symbol from a right-click or keyboard shortcut and generally will make finding your way around so easy that the size of the file will be irrelevant.

On the other hand perhaps you have a good editor and just need to learn how to do those things in it.

Comment: This does not answer my question at all. I would like to split classes into their own, separate files. I'm looking for a tool. How I organize my work is not an issue here.

Comment: You're asking for advice. I'm giving you advice. You don't have to take the advice... However you will have to reveal the platform and editor you are currently using as lots of the tools are specific to platform, editor, or development environment. You might already have such tools and just don't know it!

Comment: If there are so many of them, please just provide an example which suits my question best. I'm still looking for a best configuration for this project, since it combines many technologies. But - as I said - I will use it only to split the code - how I will work with it after can change and is totally irrelevant. Thank you.

Comment: @er453r, My advice is "don't do it". Asking someone to recommend a tool to do something that person thinks you shouldn't do is like asking someone what tool is best for cutting your foot off. **However:** If you really want to split the code - Just copy and paste as Pubby says above. The present 6 code files will then just become a bunch of #include directives to include the newly generated files. This has the added bonus that you will learn how the code is structured as you go about dividing it up - something you will not get from a tool.

Comment: Guys, I'm really thankful for your answers, but I'm not looking for a "good practice" advice. I need to get this done and I'm looking for a best way to do it.

Comment: @er453r I told you: If you really must, Just do it by hand and move on.